# SQL Query difficult

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two Tables like:

```
id_image   id_things   url_image   id_type_image
    1          1       photo.jpg         1
    2          1       sketch.jpg        2
    3          2       324532.pdf        3
    4          3       345323.pdf        3
```

And:

```
id_type_image   description
      1            photo
      2            sketch
      3           datasheet
```

I want this query result:

```
id_things   url_image(photo)   url_image(sketch)
    1         photo.jpg           sketch.jpg 
    2           NULL                NULL
    3           NULL                NULL
```

How would I have to perform the query to get the result?

Comment: What happened to the datasheets?

Comment: Please describe the logic behind the result, I don't see it. Have You tried to come up with some query so far?

Comment: @Franki, We are not here to do your homework/assignment for you. Mention what you have done so far and explain where you are stuck. Before asking such questions, google up and try to do it yourself.

Comment: I've been trying for 3 hours. I'm stuck

Comment: select id_things,max(url_image) as photo, min(url_image) as sketch from image i where id_type_image = 1 or id_type_image = 2
group by id_things

Comment: I only obtain one result with this query...

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
select
e.id_thing,
(select i.url_image from image i where i.id_thing = e.id_thing and i.id_type_image = 1) as photo,
(select i.url_image from image i where i.id_thing = e.id_thing and i.id_type_image = 2) as sketch,
(select i.url_image from image i where i.id_thing = e.id_thing and i.id_type_image = 3) as datasheet
(
    select distinct
    i.id_thing
    from image i
) e
```

Comment: Thank you but not return the result I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

Solved!! Result:

```
select id_things, (select url_image from image ii where id_type_image = 1 and ii.id_things = i.id_things) as photo, (select url_image from image ii where id_type_image = 2 and ii.id_things = i.id_things) as sketch from image i 
group by id_things
order by id_things
```

Thank you @Abihabi87 You showed me the way!

Answer (score 0):

I think Pivot will resolve your issue.

```
WITH table_1 AS
     (SELECT 1 id_image, 1 id_things, 'photo.jpg' url_image, 1 id_type_image
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 2 id_image, 1 id_things, 'sketch.jpg' url_image, 2 id_type_image
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 3 id_image, 2 id_things, '324532.pdf' url_image, 3 id_type_image
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 4 id_image, 3 id_things, '345323.pdf' url_image, 3 id_type_image
        FROM DUAL),
     table_2 AS
     (SELECT 1 id_type_image, 'photo' description
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 2 id_type_image, 'sketch' description
        FROM DUAL
      UNION
      SELECT 3 id_type_image, 'datasheet' description
        FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id_things, y.description, x.url_image
          FROM table_1 x JOIN table_2 y ON x.id_type_image = y.id_type_image
               )
  pivot (
  min(url_image) 
  for description in 
  ('photo' "url_image(photo)",'sketch' "url_image(sketch)"));
```